# Netscaler monitoring custom headers

Tags: http, http-headers, jetty, jetty-9, netscaler

I'm trying to setup monitoring (http-ecv) with authorization header, but I'm getting illegal character or header folding error (jetty 9.3)

**1. example**

GET /somepath/somepage.html HTTP/1.1

Server Running

\r\nAuthorization: Basic somestring=\r\n

*Response "HTTP1.1 400 Illegal character SPACE=''\r\n"*

**2. example**

GET /somepath/somepage.html

Server Running

HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Basic somestring=\r\n

*Response HTTP/1.1 400 Illegal character VCHAR='/'\r\n*

This example was working on older jetty version

**3.example**

GET /somepath/somepage.html

Server Running

\r\nHTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Basic somestring=\r\n

*Response HTTP1.1 400 Header Folding\r\n*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

try the solution on the article https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX117142

edit to add more context: the article describes how to create a monitor for a back end server that requests basic authentication with a user name and password.

Summarized:

```
add lb monitor test_login_tcp TCP-ECV -send "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Basic YOURBASE64USERPW\r\nHost: IP_or_FQDN\r\n\r\n" -recv 200 -LRTM ENABLED
```